# find match between two comma separated string in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I just tried to get a query like below.

```
SELECT id FROM users WHERE ['Mumbai','Lenma'] IN location
```

where users table is below

```
id location
1  Mumbai,India
2  Lenma,Germany
3  Holi,Finland
```

Please help me to find this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp`:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE location regexp 'Mumbai|Lenma'
```

You can also use multiple `like` comparisons:

```
SELECT id
FROM users
WHERE location LIKE 'Mumbai%' OR
      location LIKE 'Lenma%' ;
```

This, of course, assumes that the strings you are looking for are at the beginning (otherwise put a "%" before).

Comment: You have to use `%Mumbai%` in case appear on the middle. Also be carfull because can find partial match. Bottom line better use normalize tables instead of separated comma fields

Answer (score 0):

You can also use SUBSTRING_INDEX for MySQL.

```
SELECT id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(location, ',' 1) AS city
FROM `users` WHERE 
city = 'Mumbai' OR city = 'Lenma';
```